# what is happening in this code and what will be the basic implementation of the following without the "with" keyword

Tags: javascript

I was going through a code base that was creating a multi-platform package management and module system for JavaScript.

I found a path of code that was extracting from withing the function that is associated with the "exports" variable.
I have attached the code snippet below, and on running the snippet you will find the "print" object gets extracted from the function.
I want to know two things:-

1. How is this code working?
2. can this code be implemented in a more easier way without the with statement?

```js
var context = {
  exports: {}
};

var fn = (function(args) {
  with(args) {
    return function logger() {
      exports = {
        print: function(res) {
          console.log(res);
        }
      }

    }
  }
});
fn = fn(context);
fn.call();
context.exports.print('hello World'); //Prints the hello world
```

Comment: `eval` and `with`. The two *best parts* of JavaScript in one script.

Comment: Before you ask "how is the code working", you should ask "what is the code supposed to do"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, evaluating a non-string is pointless. Remove the `eval` call and just use the function.

Technically, the `with` statement does this:

> The `with` statement adds an [object environment record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1) for a
>   computed object to the [lexical environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2) of the current
>   execution context. It then executes a statement using this augmented
>   [lexical environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2). Finally, it restores the original [lexical
>   environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2).

Basically, this means that when you assign an object to the identifier `exports`, it becomes a property of `args`.

Don't do this. The `with` statement has bad performance and is not allowed in strict mode. Just assign the property normally.

```
var fn = function(args) {
  return function logger() {
    args.exports = {
      print: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I have removed the eval, and the script works ok, but in this assignment i cant add exports as a property to any argument, that's why i was using the with, can you help me with another solution? Thanks a lot

Comment: What makes you think "i cant add exports as a propety to any argument"?

Comment: I am using this code to compile the following file structure https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js/blob/master/example/logger.js,, the repo is in https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js

Comment: Again, in which case does your code work and mine doesn't?

Comment: i think we are having a mis-communication. your code works fine, but the problem is that i cant use it for the project that i have mentioned you in the comment above, i need to keep the fille exports free of any argument property, you can check the github link that i have posted (you can run the project), i assume, i will be able to better express my idea to you that way,

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem with `args.exports` if you can use `with(args)`

Comment: please run this project https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js, to use the arguments.exports i have to change the syntax of the https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js/blob/master/example/calculator.js and https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js/blob/master/example/logger.js files. I hope atlast i am able to express mself :)

Comment: very sorry for the argument, i did'nt understd you at first, thanks for the help, i have edited your comment with a code snippet.

Comment: @goku Well yes, you really *should* change the syntax of those files. And if you don't want to edit the source files, you can still do it programmatically it [here](https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js/blob/2c8d1fce76212287ddbab55fa99e67c45a5d1954/packages/jsio.js#L393). Btw, why don't you just use ES6 syntax for exports and imports?