# javascript understanding context in recursive call code cleanup without "with" keyword

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recreate the following functionality [code here](https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js/blob/master/packages/jsio.js#L142) in the following manner without the "with keyword" as pointed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913938/what-is-happening-in-this-code-and-what-will-be-the-basic-implementation-of-the/34914029#34914029)

```js
function imports(from, as, exportInto) {
  exportInto = exportInto || {};

  var ctx = {
    exports: {},
    imports: function(from, as) {
      imports(from, as, ctx);
    }
  };
  from(ctx);
  exportInto[as] = ctx.exports;
};

var logger = (function(args) {
  args.exports = {
    print: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  }
});


var calculator = (function(args) {
  args.imports(logger, 'logger');
  args.exports = {
    add: function(a, b) {
      logger.print(a + b);
    }
  }
});

var app = (function(args) {
  args.imports(calculator, 'calculator');
  calculator.add(2, 3);
});


imports(app, 'app');
```

but, on running the calculaltor.add function is not found, I tried to debug the problem , but i fail to understand the bug.

EDIT

purpose of this code is to get previous context export returned into the import.
i.e `args.imports(calculator, 'calculator');` will be replaced with

```
calculator.add = function(a, b) {
      logger.print(a + b);
    }
```

similar to [this line that i am trying to mimic](https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js/blob/master/packages/jsio.js#L182)

EDIT 2

also the purpose of this code is to have a [similar looking structure](https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js/tree/master/example) withing a singleton file structure.

Comment: What is the purpose/goal of this code?  What are you trying to achieve?  I ask because this code is very hard to follow conceptually.  If I loaded it up in a debugger and traced through it, maybe I'd have a chance at understanding what it is attempting to do, but it seems that a question here that wants to attract answers should explain itself in a way that one doesn't have to go to that level of effort just to figure out the point of the code.

Comment: @jfriend00, the purpose of the code mentioned in github link is to create a modular javascript import statement, if you run  [this file] (https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js/blob/master/index.js) using node, you will understand the import export statement.
The code that i have mentioned in here , is the similar replication of [this function](https://github.com/souparno/jsio.js/blob/master/packages/jsio.js#L142),the expected output of this code is to get args.imports(calculator, 'calculator'); line return add: function(a, b) {
      logger.print(a + b);
    }

Comment: This importing code makes no sense. Either you want `args.import('calculator')` and refer to it using `args.calculator.…`, or you want something like `var calculator = args.import('calculator');`. (same for `logger`)

Comment: I have to repeat my comment from that other post: You really should change the syntax of those files. And if you don't want to edit the source files, you can still do it programmatically in the loader code. Btw, why don't you just use ES6 syntax for exports and imports?

Comment: @Bergi, i am not using ES6 for two reasons, 1. i want the import syntax resemble java/c#, 2. i am compiling this module https://github.com/gameclosure/timestep with jsio

Comment: @goku: Well then at least make it actual Java syntax, not just a JS method call. Those simply don't work as declarations. And it's a bad idea to try letting JS resemble Java.

Comment: @goku: Not sure I understand. Are you forking jsio to improve their module system, or are you trying to roll your own that needs to be compatible with jsio?

Comment: @Bergi, i am trying to roll my own, that will be compatible to the modulation of the original jsio

Comment: @goku: Well, jsio-style code depends on that `with` statement, you cannot avoid that. If you want to avoid it, best use the pattern from ES6 modules, it's well-dokumented and though-out and you will find a large infrastructure for it (both for parsing, if you want to roll your own loader, or even for using another loader than jsio some day). You still might be able to use jsio as a loader, but with ES6 modules.

Comment: @Bergi, i cannot agree with you in that, a with statement is replaceable as was pointed out [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913938/what-is-happening-in-this-code-and-what-will-be-the-basic-implementation-of-the?lq=1)

Comment: @goku: Well, no, it is not. Surely you can replace that assignment (which the other question was about) with a property assignment, but it is impossible to import variables (like the `console` identifier) into a scope in a way that is as dynamic as the jsio approach. Use static resolution (like it is possible with ES6 modules) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function imports(from, as, exportInto) {
  exportInto = exportInto || {};

  var ctx = {
    exports: {},
    imports: function(from, as) {
      imports(from, as, ctx);
    }
  };
  from(ctx);
  exportInto[as] = ctx.exports;
};

var logger = (function(args) {
  args.exports = {
    print: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  }
});


var calculator = (function(args) {
  args.imports(logger, 'logger');
  args.exports = {
    add: function(a, b) {
      args.logger.print(a + b);
    }
  }
});

var app = (function(args) {
  args.imports(calculator, 'calculator');
  args.calculator.add(2, 3);
});


imports(app, 'app');
```